# How reduce cassandra virtual memory usage?

Tags: java, windows-7, cassandra, jvm, virtual-memory

Is there a settings in cassandra to reduce it memory usage? I understand that cassandra manages memory well, but for testing purposes I do not want to spent 6Gb memory only when cassandra service running on my windows mchine.

**UPDATED**

I have tired setting `disk_access_mode: standart` instead of `disk_access_mode: auto`. It was not help. Also I pay attention that in cassandra 2.0.9 `cassandra.yaml` file do not contains `disk_access_mode` by  default. So it seems (but I not sure) that `disk_access_mode` was removed from cassandra.

Answer (score 30):

As @catpaws points out the key is in the documentation at [Tuning Java resources](https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsTuneJVM.html) and cassandra-env.sh (on my mac I found it in /usr/local/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh) but she falls short of answering the question.

So here is what I did and what happened:
I looked at my Activity Monitor and noticed the java (cassandra) memory usage being ~4GB. Then I read the docs and found that the ~4GB is around the same as the allocated heap using the formula

```
max(min(1/2 ram, 1024MB), min(1/4 ram, 8GB)
```

Then I edited **cassandra-env.sh** where it says "Override these to set the amount..." and set

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="2GB"
```

form the original 4GB. I also set

HEAP_NEWSIZE="400M"

but that is not necessary to reduce the memory usage.

I restarted cassandra and checked the Activity Monitor. It said the Memory usage  java (cassandra) was now only ~2GB.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me here.

Answer (score 1):

The conf/cassandra-env.sh file control environment settings for Cassandra. See comments in the file and docs: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html

Comment: May be I missed somethink, but there is no word about **virtual** memory tuning, only jvm heap and general RAM advices.

Comment: No. This did not help. :(

Comment: Dead link, 404.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, we found `disk_access_mode: mmap_index_only` provides the best results.  Also helps to stay out of the Linux OOM killer radar